# New field of custom AbstractUser not showing up in Django admin despite overriding the default admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I have added the field `introduction` to my `CustomUser` model and made the proper migrations:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    introduction = models.CharField(max_length=5000, null=True, blank=True, default="")

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('user_detail', args=[str(self.username)])
```

`admin.py` overrides the default admin for users:

```
CustomUser = get_user_model()

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'introduction',]

admin.site.register(CustomUser,CustomUserAdmin)
```

`forms.py`:

```
class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username',)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ('username', 'introduction',)
```

Despite this, when I try to modify a user in the Django admin, the `introduction` field doesn't appear.

I am using django 3.0.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add *introduction* field name in *fieldsets* list of CustomUserAdmin because it is already implemented in the base class which is the reason of not showing the new field in django admin automatically.

According to django documentation:

> fieldsets is a list of two-tuples, in which each two-tuple represents
>   a  on the admin form page. (A  is a “section” of
>   the form.)
>
> The two-tuples are in the format (name, field_options), where name is
>   a string representing the title of the fieldset and field_options is a
>   dictionary of information about the fieldset, including a list of
>   fields to be displayed in it.

I got *fieldsets* from AbstractUser class and extended by *introduction* field. This code snippet must help you to show new user model field in admin:

```py
from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
    list_display = ['username', 'introduction',]
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'introduction')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
```

Comment: The `_` is the getttext from translations?

Comment: Yep, `from django.utils.translation import gettext, gettext_lazy as _` I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the ideal way to do it,but what I did was making changes in the field_sets of UserAdmin like the following:

```
class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('username', 'password','introduction')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {
            'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions'),
        }),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_form = CustomUserCreationForm
    form = CustomUserChangeForm
    model = CustomUser
```

I just added introduction to the fields,and it appears on the admin site